# Hamburger Menu WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Как можно реализовать такой контрол в WPF? Во многих win10 приложениях есть гамбургер кнопка, при нажатии на которую появляется меню. При выборе какого-то элемента из этого меню оно закрывается. По сути мне нужен эффект точно такой же как на скриншоте, который я приложил к вопросу.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вам на телефоне или реально в десктопном WPF?

Comment: Десктопном WPF.

Comment: Использовать анимацию со свойством margin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если ширина контента фиксирована, всё просто. Но это не само собой разумеется, поэтому придумаем, как использовать layout manager для подсчёта нужных нам длин. Мне пришло в голову достаточно универсальное, но объёмное решение. (Буду рад, если кто-то сможет его упростить.)

Излагаю по частям.

Сначала нижняя, неподвижная часть контента.

```
<Grid Background="DimGray" Name="BottomGrid">
    <Image Source="https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWDPv.png"/>
</Grid>
```

Тут всё просто, грид с контентом. Я дал ему имя, чтобы сослаться на его ширину позже.

Затем, движущаяся часть. Сделаем ещё один грид, ширину привяжем к ширине `BottomGrid`. Смещение в сторону будет делать при помощи `Margin`'а.

```
<Grid Background="WhiteSmoke" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=BottomGrid}">
    ...
</Grid>
```

Как будем определять `Margin`? Нам нужно, чтобы он изменялся от 0 до ширины `BottomGrid` минус предопределённая константа (например, 50 пикселей). Поскольку такую константу задать не просто, заведём для этих целей невидимый измеряющий грид:

```
<Grid Margin="0,0,50,0" Height="0" Name="OffsetBottomGrid"/>
```

Его ширина будет равна максимальному маргину.

Но привязать анимацию к этой ширине нельзя, т. к. она в принципе изменяемая. Поэтому будем анимировать коэффициент от 0 до 1, и устанавливать маргин как произведение этого коэффициента на ширину `OffsetBottomGrid`. Нам понадобится для этого конвертер, который умножает числа, и превращает результат в `Thickness`:

```
class ThicknessMultiplyingConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter,
                          CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return new Thickness() { Left = values.Cast<double>().Aggregate((x, y) => x * y) };
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter,
                                CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Теперь, где хранить этот коэффициент? Можно было бы завести для этого attached property, но мы просто используем ещё один невидимый измерительный грид. Получится такое:

```
<Grid Background="WhiteSmoke" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=BottomGrid}">
    <Grid.Margin>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource TMult}">
            <Binding Path="ActualWidth" ElementName="OffsetBottomGrid"/>
            <Binding Path="ActualWidth" ElementName="MeasureGrid"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </Grid.Margin>
    <Image Source="https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWDPv.png"/>
</Grid>
```

Теперь нам нужно немного магии, которая бы вычисляла и анимировала нужную ширину у измерительного грида. Нам нужно включённое и выключенное состояние, для этого снова воспользуемся `Tag`'ом.

```
<Grid Name="MeasureGrid" Height="0" Width="0">
    <Grid.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Grid">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Tag">
                    <Trigger.Value>
                        <sys:Boolean>False</sys:Boolean>
                    </Trigger.Value>
                    <Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"
                                                 To="1" Duration="0:0:1">
                                    <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                        <QuarticEase EasingMode="EaseIn"/>
                                    </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                </DoubleAnimation>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </Trigger.EnterActions>
                    <Trigger.ExitActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"
                                                To="0" Duration="0:0:1">
                                    <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                        <QuarticEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                                    </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                </DoubleAnimation>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </Trigger.ExitActions>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Style>
</Grid>
```

Устанавливаем триггер на переключение `Tag` в `True`. В триггере запускаем анимацию `Width` от 0 до 1. Для триггера по значению свойства пришлось сделать стиль.

Осталось подцепить что-нибудь, что переключало бы нужной свойство, и всё.

Готовый код:

```
<Window x:Class="SlidingPanel.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SlidingPanel"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:ThicknessMultiplyingConverter x:Key="TMult"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Background="DimGray" Name="BottomGrid">
            <Image Source="https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWDPv.png"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Margin="0,0,50,0" Height="0" Name="OffsetBottomGrid"/>

        <Grid Name="MeasureGrid" Height="0" Width="0">
            <Grid.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Grid">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="Tag">
                            <Trigger.Value>
                                <sys:Boolean>False</sys:Boolean>
                            </Trigger.Value>
                            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" To="1" Duration="0:0:1">
                                            <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                                <QuarticEase EasingMode="EaseIn"/>
                                            </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                        </DoubleAnimation>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" To="0" Duration="0:0:1">
                                            <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                                <QuarticEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                                            </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                        </DoubleAnimation>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </Trigger.ExitActions>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Grid.Style>
        </Grid>

        <Grid Background="WhiteSmoke" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=BottomGrid}">
            <Grid.Margin>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource TMult}">
                    <Binding Path="ActualWidth" ElementName="OffsetBottomGrid"/>
                    <Binding Path="ActualWidth" ElementName="MeasureGrid"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </Grid.Margin>
            <Image Source="https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWDPv.png"/>
        </Grid>
        <ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding Tag, ElementName=MeasureGrid}" Grid.Row="1" Content="Flip"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Спасибо, именно это мне и нужно было!

Comment: @Lightness: Пожалуйста!