# Как анимировать динамически создаваемые контролы XAML

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1

У меня есть список, с привязкой к данным. В этом списке есть элемент, который требуется анимировать. Допустим гиппотечиская страничка может выглядеть так:

```
<Page
x:Class="MyProject.MyPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:MyProject"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:i="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
xmlns:core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"
xmlns:media="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Media"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
<Page.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Name="Show_Control">
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Control"
                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding test}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Background="White">
                    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Tapped">
                            <media:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource Show_Control}"/>
                        </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>

                    <TextBlock Text="Hello!"/>
                    <StackPanel x:Name="Control" 
                                Height="30" 
                                Background="#000" 
                                Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

В данном примере по Тапу на элементе списка должен появляться скрытый черный квадратик. Однако на практике приложение падает с ошибкой

> System.Exception: No installed components were detected.
>   Cannot resolve TargetName Control.
>
> at Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Animation.Storyboard.Begin()
>   at Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Media.ControlStoryboardAction.Execute(Object sender, Object parameter)
>   at Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity.Interaction.ExecuteActions(Object sender, ActionCollection actions, Object parameter)
>   at Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core.EventTriggerBehavior.OnEvent(Object sender, Object eventArgs)

Может можно как-то по-другому сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У меня сработало так (пробовал только на UWP под Windows 10):

```
<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="Put_Name_Here">
        <Grid Background="White">
            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Tapped">
                    <media:ControlStoryboardAction>
                        <media:ControlStoryboardAction.Storyboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                    Storyboard.TargetName="Control"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </media:ControlStoryboardAction.Storyboard>
                    </media:ControlStoryboardAction>
                </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>

            <TextBlock Text="Hello!"/>
            <StackPanel x:Name="Control" 
                        Height="30" 
                        Background="#000" 
                        Visibility="Collapsed"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding test}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Put_Name_Here}"/>
</Grid>
```

Проблема в том, что имя `Control`, на которое ссылается ваша анимация через `Storyboard.TargetName`, должно быть видимо на этапе компиляции. Когда анимация и `DataTemplate` описаны вместе, они видят друг друга.

---

Обновление: если вам нужно проигрывать разные анимации, можно использовать переключение в code-behind. Например, так:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="Put_Name_Here">
    <Grid Background="White" Tapped="Grid_Tapped" Name="InnerGrid">
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Storyboard x:Key="SwitchOn">
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Control"
                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
            <Storyboard x:Key="SwitchOff">
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Control"
                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed"/>
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Grid.Tag>
            <x:Boolean>False</x:Boolean>
        </Grid.Tag>
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <core:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{Binding Tag, ElementName=InnerGrid}">
                <core:DataTriggerBehavior.Value>
                    <x:Boolean>True</x:Boolean>
                </core:DataTriggerBehavior.Value>
                <media:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource SwitchOn}"/>
            </core:DataTriggerBehavior>
            <core:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{Binding Tag, ElementName=InnerGrid}">
                <core:DataTriggerBehavior.Value>
                    <x:Boolean>False</x:Boolean>
                </core:DataTriggerBehavior.Value>
                <media:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource SwitchOff}"/>
            </core:DataTriggerBehavior>
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>

        <TextBlock Text="Hello!"/>
        <StackPanel x:Name="Control" 
                        Height="30" 
                        Background="#000" 
                        Visibility="Collapsed"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

и в code-behind:

```
void Grid_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var grid = (Grid)sender;
    grid.Tag = !(bool)grid.Tag;
}
```

---

Ну и если вам не нужна реальная анимация, а только включить/выключить видимость элемента, можно ещё проще:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="Put_Name_Here">
    <Grid Background="White" Tapped="Grid_Tapped">
        <TextBlock Text="Hello!"/>
        <StackPanel x:Name="Control" 
                        Height="30" 
                        Background="#000" 
                        Visibility="Collapsed"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

и в code-behind

```
void Grid_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var grid = (Grid)sender;
    var control = (StackPanel)grid.FindName("Control");
    control.Visibility = control.Visibility == Visibility.Collapsed ?
        Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

---

Ну и ещё один вариант, без code-behind, но с одним конвертером. Идея в том, что мы по событию tapped меняем значение `Tag` между `true` и `false`, а к этому значению через `DataTrigger` прикрепляем анимацию.

```
<Page.Resources>
    <local:BooleanNegatingConverter x:Key="BooleanNegatingConverter"/>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="Put_Name_Here">
        <Grid Background="White" Name="InnerGrid">
            <Grid.Resources>
                <Storyboard x:Key="SwitchOn">
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Control"
                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
                <Storyboard x:Key="SwitchOff">
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Control"
                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </Grid.Resources>
            <Grid.Tag>
                <x:Boolean>False</x:Boolean>
            </Grid.Tag>
            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Tapped">
                    <core:ChangePropertyAction
                        TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=InnerGrid}" PropertyName="Tag"
                        Value="{Binding Tag, ElementName=InnerGrid,
                                    Converter={StaticResource BooleanNegatingConverter}}"/>
                </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                <core:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{Binding Tag, ElementName=InnerGrid}">
                    <core:DataTriggerBehavior.Value>
                        <x:Boolean>True</x:Boolean>
                    </core:DataTriggerBehavior.Value>
                    <media:ControlStoryboardAction
                        Storyboard="{StaticResource SwitchOn}"/>
                </core:DataTriggerBehavior>
                <core:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{Binding Tag, ElementName=InnerGrid}">
                    <core:DataTriggerBehavior.Value>
                        <x:Boolean>False</x:Boolean>
                    </core:DataTriggerBehavior.Value>
                    <media:ControlStoryboardAction
                        Storyboard="{StaticResource SwitchOff}"/>
                </core:DataTriggerBehavior>
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>

            <TextBlock Text="Hello!"/>
            <StackPanel x:Name="Control" 
                            Height="30" 
                            Background="#000" 
                            Visibility="Collapsed"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>
```

Вам понадобится всего лишь простой конвертер:

```
class BooleanNegatingConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string lang)
    {
        return !(bool)value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string lang)
    {
        return !(bool)value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Этот подход действительно сработал. Огромное спасибо!

Comment: Я когда-то находил, но теперь никак не могу найти. Если мне нужно сделать откат анимации, например нажали  - появился квадрат, нажали второй раз - пропал. Толи какими-то мультитриггерами задавалось, толи еще чем. Можете подсказать в сторону какого тега копать?

Comment: @Олег: Сейчас найду пример обратной анимации, где-то был недавно.

Comment: @Олег: Например, вот с триггерами: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/502012/10105, http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/487165/10105 (понимаю, что это не совсем то).

Comment: В тех примерах, как я понял разные анимации висят на событиях по разным элементам. А у меня получается так, что на один и тот-же грид, одно и то-же событие тапа, только в случае если уже отработала первая анимация(Показали квадратик), то запускать вторую(Скрываем его), и наоборот.

Comment: Или такое в принципе не возможно?

Comment: @Олег: В тех примерах есть один элемент, и в нём триггер с EnterActions и ExitActions. Можно стащить логику из Hamburger Menu: там есть булева переменная (Tag), которая управляет состоянием, и анимации завязываются на неё. Переменную можно переключать, например, в code-behind.

Comment: @Олег: Обновил ответ, пробуйте.

Comment: Заработало. Огромное спасибо!

Comment: @Олег: Пожалуйста! Рад, что получилось!

Comment: Простите, что беспокою в старом вопросе, но вновь столкнулся с проблемой. Если описать анимацию в `DataTemplate`, то ее прекрасно видят элементы, находящиеся вместе с ней внутри этого `DataTemplate`. Но если сама анимация ссылается на внешний элемент, за пределами `DataTemplate` и вообще за пределами `Page.Resources`, то она его уже не видит. Есть ли какой-то `Короткий` путь сослать такую анимацию на внешний элемент, или уже проще через `code-behind` написать?

Comment: @Олег: Совсем короткого пути я не знаю. Я бы, например, делал так: (1) анимировал какое-нибудь «ненужное» свойство у элемента (например, `Tag` прекрасно подходит), (2) прибиндил бы то, что нужно анимировать, к этому свойству.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку. Сделаю тогда через событие в `code-behind`, так как прибиндить анимацию к свойству динамического элемента мне пока не по силам.

Comment: @Олег: Как-то так должно покатить: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/484813/10105. В том примере через триггер изменяется свойство `Tag`, а другие к нему привязываются через `Binding`. В вашем случае у вас `Tag` будет изменяться не через триггер, а через анимацию.

Comment: Получилось, спасибо )

Comment: @Олег: Пожалуйста!

Answer (score 0):

рискну предположить что невидит **TargetName="Control"** в

```
<ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Control"
```

Comment: Любое название не видит(